# Is there a limit to the amount of .animate()'s you can use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Im using .animate to move a red css circle around a picture of a map. After the 5th animate, the jquery .animate's stop working. Is there a limit to the amount that I can use?

```
 function doAnimate() {
  $("#animate").css({top: "510px", left: "950px"})
  .animate({top: "470px", left: "955px"}, 1500)
  .animate({top: "470px", left: "1050px"}, 1500)
  .animate({top: "370px", left: "1047px"}, 1500)
  .animate({top: "370px", left: "865px"}, 1500)
  .animate({top: "310px", left: "895x"}, 1500)
  .animate({top: "310px", left: "865x"}, 1500);
};
doAnimate();
setInterval(doAnimate, 9100);
```

The last .animate command wont work, but the other 5 ontop of it do. Why does it stop working after 5 .animate's?

Comment: No, there isn't a limit. As a side note, there is no need to set the `top` again if it is the same value. Your second animation css can just modify the `left`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `"x"` at last two calls to `.animate()` , not valid `unit` value parameter passed as `value` to set . Try changing `"x"` to `"px"`

```
.animate({top: "310px", left: "895px"}, 1500)
.animate({top: "310px", left: "865px"}, 1500);
```

Comment: How do you catch small mistakes like that? o.O

Comment: @jessica _"After the 5th animate, the jquery .animate's stop working."_

Comment: You actually don't need any quotes or to set a px value : `.animate({top: 310, left: 895}, 1500)`.

Comment: @Shikkediel Yes, `.animate()` unit default to "px" value , though could be set to other valid unit value , e.g., "em", "%", "pt" . OP appear to set "px" directly ; perhaps to avoid question as to what unit value is at source ?

Comment: I suspect OP wasn't aware of it but you are right about the other values of course. There are also *some* properties that are not automatically set as `px`, `line-height` for example...